# How do I add html styles in Vaadin's RichTextEditor like was possible in Vaadin 8 RichTextArea

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin8, vaadin14

For example in Vaadin 8 with the `RichTextArea` I could add `<style>` in the html and that would be respected. As well I could add `table` (yes old school but still valid html) however in `RichTextEditor` any `<style>` is completely removed and the `tables` are changed to `<p>` tags. I'm trying to transition an app from Vaadin 8 and this it is critically important to be able to edit text through html directly within the application as a lot of the existing data is in html. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The new RichTextEditor introduced in Vaadin 10 is based on the [Quill](https://quilljs.com/) library, which does not yet support tables (https://github.com/quilljs/quill/issues/117).

The examples in the [documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/components/rich-text-editor) give a pretty good picture of what formatting is supported.

Styles can be applied inline to each element, and by applying a stylesheet to the RTE component using a [theme](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/styling/custom-theme/creating-custom-theme) or @CssImport

There are also add-ons based on other libraries that might be a better fit, e.g. https://vaadin.com/directory/component/ckeditorvaadin and https://vaadin.com/directory/component/tinymceeditorforvaadin, but I haven't checked their table or styling support.